# How do we trust power of compounding with mutual fund SIP

Tags: trading, mutual-funds, compound-interest, long-term

When I search for SIP Mutual fund plans, often I see huge money returns in the long run.

But when I research, it's usually mentioned as Power of compounding, that's how they're able to return such a hefty amount.

[image]

Their only condition is 40 years of period and 100000 Rupees(1 lakh) per month and 11.5% returns is attainable. I guess, because there are so many plans which offer more than that anyways.

Can someone help me understand if it's practical to expect near a 1000000000 Rupees (100 crore) as total returns?

**Update:**

Inflation rate in my country is 7.5 then Is it right to subtract the inflation rate in returns rate (11.5) and whatever the amount that I'm getting now.. and whatever things I can buy right now with that amount is what I'd be able to buy after 40 years ? would that be right assumption to make ?

[image]

Comment: Is your trouble with the concept of compounding? Compounding, especially with 11.5%, is a really strong effect (it doubles your amount every 6-7 years), but not necessarily intuitive (["Would you rather have a million dollars or a penny on day one, doubled every day until day 30?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_and_chessboard_problem)).

Comment: ha ha .. good one

Answer (score 5):

40 years is a long time, and 11.5% is a large interest rate. They combine to produce a huge return. This is easier to see if you use simpler numbers. If you start with 100, and get 10%, after 1 year it's 110, after 2 years 121, after just ten years it's almost 260 -- much more than doubled -- after 20 years nearly 7 times the original, and so on. You can do this math yourself to see what compounding can do.

It's sensible to ask "is that possible?" and the thing is, yes it's possible given those assumptions, but are those assumptions possible? Can the fund manager get 11.5% returns for so long? Can you put money in and not use it from age 20 to age 60?

Also, thanks to inflation, a particular amount of money 40 years from now won't buy what it would buy today. So if you're thinking "I could invest one month's rent, and after 40 years that would buy a whole house!" no it wouldn't.

A more useful measure of investment returns is the percentage after inflation. If you can get 4% after inflation (and taxes, if it's not a sheltered instrument), then you're doing well.

Comment: Please find the question update.Inflation rate in my country is 7.5 then Is it right to subtract the inflation rate in returns rate (11.5) and whatever the amount that I'm getting now.. and whatever things I can buy right now with that amount is what I'd be able to buy after 40 years ? would that be right assumption to make ?

Comment: well, it's a little more complicated than that, but yes as a rough guess you could try compounding 4% (the difference between 11.5 and 7.5) over 40 years and that's what your savings would be equivalent to

Comment: Thanks. That makes very good sense.But do you think doing SIP for such a long run is not a good idea. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't know what a SIP is. But saving even a small amount of money for a long time is better than waiting and then saving a large amount of money for a short time. So if you can save, save. Should you use this instrument? I do not know.

Comment: Thanks , that helps. SIP is systematic Investment plan.. you just pay the mutual fund company a fixed amount every month.